# If statement in a sql query

Tags: sql

is there anyway that i can basically do the following in a sql clause ,(i know syntax isn't correct, but that's not the point, it's the idea)

`set rs = select title, copy, masterID from table1`

`//if the masterID is not 0 then instead of using the copy from table1, use the copy from table2`

`if masterID<>0 then`
`set rs2 = "select copy from table2 where masterID =" & masterID`
`copy = rs(0)`

I hope that makes sense. Look forward to hearing your responses. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but the syntax can very by server.  What is your underlying database server?  MySQL?, SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
select title, 
       case when t1.masterID <> 0 then t2.case else t1.case end as copy, 
       masterID
from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2
    on t1.masterID = t2.masterID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @masterID int
if(@masterID <> 0)
    select copy from table2 where masterId = @masterID
 else
    select title, copy, masterID from table1
```